# Which folder or files created in vagrant should not be push in a repository on GitHub

Tags: github, vagrant, development-environment

I would like to create a vagrant with some utilities installed, such like a configured LAMP, npm installed, etc... and later doing a push in a public github account.

I should create a .gitignore file with which restrictions? A simple vagrant project have this structure:

- .vagrant (folder).
- html (folder).
- vagrantfile (file).

And I don't want some script shell for install the utilities when the user run vagrant up. For that I want to share an environment with everything and installed via vagrant ssh.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You definitely want your `Vagrantfile`. That's what defines your Vagrant environment. And you almost certainly want to ignore `.vagrant/`.

[gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/) seems [to agree](https://www.gitignore.io/api/vagrant):

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/vagrant

### Vagrant ###
.vagrant/
```

You might also want to use this utility with the rest of your stack, e.g. [here is a `.gitignore` generated for Composer, NodeJS and Vagrant](https://www.gitignore.io/api/vagrant%2Ccomposer%2Cnode).